# Path "localhost" with xampp

Tags: c#, xampp

I am using an absolute path in my code where I have some mp3 files that I show in a list. How can I access a folder that is in "localhost/music" with xampp?

I use "visual studio" + xampp with htdocs and phpmyadmin.
Thanks

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //THIS PATH CHANGE TO "Localhost" Directory
    string rutaNovedades = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\Musica";
    //
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@rutaNovedades);
    foreach (var cancion in di.GetFiles())
    {
        lvNovedades.Items.Add(cancion.Name);
    }
    string contenidolista = "";
    contenidolista = lvNovedades.Items[0].Text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What are the problem you are having ? What is not working ? The list is empty? The directory get not found ?

Comment: Have you tried `Server.MapPath()`: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/server-mappath-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: @Rafael i make the list with the mp3 files of the directory. I've a list with names of mp3 files. But How i can use string rutaNovedades = @"localhost/music"; instead of the code? Thanks again

Comment: One more question ... The C# part is WindowsForms ? (is this part unrelated with Xamp, correct?)

Comment: @Rafael yes. Windows Form + Xampp

Comment: If it is not ASP, @RahulSharma comment will not work

Comment: Oh :( Thanks for all man! I will try with other methods.... @Rafael

Comment: You still have the option to read an Config file or pass it with parameters, or event, adding a textbox on the form with this info

Comment: An additional comment: Don't do it in the form constructor, use the Shown event. your form will be freeze until it finishes but without showing the form. Will be hard to troubleshoot

Comment: Of course! I tried with "localhost/music/song.mp3"; But getFiles() is empty and the listView havent got items

Comment: @CristianGarcia when you tried to get files from "localhost/music/song.mp3" it searched for a folder named "localhost" inside the working folder of your application (the form one)

Comment: @Rafael yesl the computer browse directory localhost, not a server localhost. i dont know how browse on local server or web server directory